# How to sort text file by labeled field?

Tags: linux, command-line, sorting

I have file with line format as follows:

`<something> <file_name> type:file <something> size:<filesize> <something>`

I would like to sort numerically it by the field "filesize" identified by label "size:". The simple key number/offset passed usually to sort program doesn't work because there is no strict separator - multiple spaces can occur before "size:" label - for example in "file_name". Is there any way to sort from command line using preceding label as a field identifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no colon in `<something>`'s, you could say:

```
sort -t : -Vk 3 file
```

Comment: Great, it works. I thought it'll try to parse 'filesize' field till the next colon but it smartly finished after last digit. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

it is hard to answer without a sample.

try something like (can be onlined, no need for \ if last char is | )

```
  awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
     if ( substr($i,1,5) == "size:" ) { print substr($i,6) " " $0 ; next ; }}'  file |
    sort -n | awk '{$1="" ; print } '
```

basically

- first awk search for size field, and put it in front
- sort with numeric argument
- last awk remove numeric argument.